# Firefox is already running, but is not responding. VSCODE PHP Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, firefox

I'm using VSCode php server extension to load a .php web page into the local browser. It works fine with other browsers but with firefox developer edition I always receive this error whenever I reload the server.

Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

Usually first I press PHPServer : Serve project , firefox opens for the first time, no error messages but after that when I press PHPServer : Reload Project, firefox always gives me that error. I think its because there is already a opened firefox browser window but firefox cannot handle a new request to reload it self. The operating system I use is a linux distribution.
could someone please help me to solve this firefox error?

Comment: This question is not particularly relevant to Linux, perhaps you would get a better response posting it on the main stackoverflow.com site?